# Retrieve data from firebase error

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

I have data on firebase like this picture:
[image]

I use this code in onCreate:

```
mRootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("About");
mRootRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            String set = "";
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                set = (String) dataSnapshot.getValue();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
```

But set is null. How can I get/retrieve data in about?

Answer (score 0):

Try passing the type of the data you want to get (`String` in this case) in the method `getValue()`.

```
mRootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("About");
mRootRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        String set = "";
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            set = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```